# Stochastic Increments

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Can anybody help me generate the increments
$\Delta$$W_n$ in mathematica.
I Know $W_{i+1}=w_i+Z_{i+1}\sqrt{\Delta t}$  where the $Z_i$ are independent and standard normal. But I cant make any code to generate the increments on Mathematica. There are codes availabe for it on Matlab which I dont understand.
Kindly help

Comment: Try `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[dt]], len]` but mathematica.SE would be more appropriate site to get answer on _Mathematica_.

Comment: Thanks. But what do you mean by len in [0, Sqrt[dt]], len]

Comment: `len` denotes the number of $\Delta W_n$ you intend to generate.